# SCORM multiple rollup action

Tags: scorm

How do I specify a multiple roll up action for example. Based on success status of any one SCO I want the overall status of the course to be satisfied and similarly based on the completion status of any of the SCO, I want the completion status of the overall course to be completed. I tried doing it by specifying 2 rollup rules but testing on scorm.com is not giving the expected result. Any clues?

```
<imsss:rollupRules objectiveMeasureWeight="1">
          <imsss:rollupRule childActivitySet="any">
            <imsss:rollupConditions conditionCombination="any">
              <imsss:rollupCondition operator="noOp" condition="completed" />
            </imsss:rollupConditions>
            <imsss:rollupAction action="completed" />           
          </imsss:rollupRule>
         <imsss:rollupRule childActivitySet="any">
            <imsss:rollupConditions conditionCombination="any">
              <imsss:rollupCondition operator="noOp" condition="satisfied" />
            </imsss:rollupConditions>
            <imsss:rollupAction action="satisfied" />           
          </imsss:rollupRule>
        </imsss:rollupRules>
```

This is what I have set but this doesnot seem to work. Can somebody point out whats wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us what undesired behavior you are seeing?

Comment: The behaviour is the link to second sco disappears and though one of the SCO has the status passed, the overall status of the course is set to failed. (1 SCO has failed status and the other SCO has the status passed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, do you mean that the status of one particular SCO controls the rolled up status? Or, do you mean that if any SCO achieves a status then the parent should also attain that status?

If it is the former, you want to just mark all of the other SCOs as not contributing to rollup. See the [Post Test Rollup golf example](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/).

If it is the later, then you will want a rollup rule on the parent that says "if any completed/satisfied then completed/satisfied".

You are on the right track by having two separate rollup rules for the separate status rollups. In fact, you need a separate rollup rule for each individual status...i.e. a rule for incomplete, a rule for completed, a rule for satisfied and a rule for not satisfied.